# Access to firebase android DB from sprng boot server

Tags: android, spring, firebase

I have an android application in which a driver gets authentificated through firebase. then when a client sends his request, the request goes to a spring boot server. my server should get access to myfirebase DB of drivers to gets longitude and latitude of the closest driver to answer the client. how can i implement that ? how can a spring boot server get access to an android firebase DB project. thank u

Comment: hey all ,this demo helpedme alot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi2dv6NcHWA i've solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firebase project is not tied to a specific technology. The fact that you have an Android app in the project does not prohibit you from accessing it from other technologies, such as Spring.

To access Firebase from a Spring project, you'd use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for Java. There are no specific steps for setting it up in Spring; you just [add the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk) to your project and use it like any other JVM developer would.

If you get stuck along the way, post a question with the specific steps you've already taken and where you are stuck.

Comment: i've tried adding sdk admin to a controller in my spring project so if i specify the path to the google-services.json i get
Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
and if i do it by setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()) i get The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. see....

Answer (score 0):

You can create the roles and add admin role to all the records created in the system. Now write the rule to allow the admin role to access the records. At server side, setup the firebase callbacks over the collections which will get notified if any thing changed.